# Problem bubbleSorting generic type in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, methods

having confusion/problem with generics. I'd just like to be able to sort and print of array of any type that is a Number class or subclass of Number. I wrote the printArray method first, which works fine. Then i wrote the bubbleSort method, but having issues calling it in the constructor. Any help?

```
public class DAB_NumberAnalyzer<T extends Number>
{
    private T[] array;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param array
     */
    public DAB_NumberAnalyzer(T[] array)
    {
        this.array = array;

        bubbleSortArray(array);
        printArray(array);
    }

    public static <T> void printArray(T[] array)
    {
        for(T element : array)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s, ", element);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void bubbleSortArray(T[] array)
    {
        int lastPos;
        int index;
        T temp;

        for(lastPos = array.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--)
        {
            for(index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++) 
            {
                if(array[index].compareTo(array[index]) > 0)
                {
                    temp = array[index];
                    array[index] = array[index + 1];
                    array[index + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the constructor, I get an error on the line where I call the bubbleSortArray method.

Error: The method bubbsleSortArray(T[]) in the type DAB_NumberAnalyzer is not applicable for the arguments (T[]).

Don't understand how I'm not getting this error with the printArray method call.

Am i placing something in the wrong spot?

Just started generics, still a bit fuzzy with it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First thing I need to say is do not mixed Class generic T and Method generic T, you are using same symbol, and probably you suppose that you can use one for other, but they are different, this is why you are getting that error.  if you remove the static and the method generic from the method signature, you may achieve.  And you can use Comparator to compare.

Answer (score 0):

`bubbleSortArray` expects `T` to extend `Comparable<T>`. The `T` of your class extends `Number` which does not extend `Comparable`. You may change your class declaration to `DAB_NumberAnalyzer<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>`.

Comment: This exactly did it! Thank you so much